# Show that $Var(X)=Var(\Bbb{E}(X|Y))+\Bbb{E}(Var(X|Y))$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Let $X\in L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\Bbb{P})$. Let $Y$ be a random variable, we define

$$Var(X|Y)=\Bbb{E}((X-\Bbb{E}(X|Y))^2|Y))$$

Show that $Var(X)=Var(\Bbb{E}(X|Y))+\Bbb{E}(Var(X|Y))$

Ok, so

$\Bbb{E}(Var(X|Y))=\Bbb{E}((X-\Bbb{E}(X|Y))^2)=\Bbb{E}(X^2)-2\Bbb{E}(X\Bbb{E}(X|Y))+\Bbb{E}(\Bbb{E}(X|Y)^2)$

While

$Var(\Bbb{E}(X|Y))=\Bbb{E}((\Bbb{E}(X|Y))^2)-[\Bbb{E}(\Bbb{E}(X|Y))]^2=\Bbb{E}((\Bbb{E}(X|Y))^2)-[\Bbb{E}(X)]^2$

Adding both, I obtain

$Var(\Bbb{E}(X|Y))+\Bbb{E}(Var(X|Y))=Var(X) + 2(\Bbb{E}(\Bbb{E}(X|Y)^2)-\Bbb{E}(X\Bbb{E}(X|Y)))$

But I don't know how to deal with $\Bbb{E}(X\Bbb{E}(X|Y))$ nor with $\Bbb{E}(\Bbb{E}(X|Y)^2)$. What can I do with those terms?

Comment: There is a mistake in the first line of your proof: you replace $Var(X\mid Y)$ by $(X - E(X\mid Y))^2$. You forgot to take the expectation conditional on $Y$.

Comment: In the definition of $Var(X|Y)$ or in taking the expectaction of $Var(X|Y)$?

Comment: Relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance

Answer (score 1):

Note that
\begin{align*}
\Bbb{E}(Var(X \mid Y))&=\Bbb{E}(X^2)-2\Bbb{E}(X\Bbb{E}(X \mid Y))+\Bbb{E}((\Bbb{E}(X \mid Y))^2)\\
&=\Bbb{E}(X^2)-2\Bbb{E}(E(X\Bbb{E}(X \mid Y) \mid Y ))+\Bbb{E}((\Bbb{E}(X \mid Y))^2)\\
&= \Bbb{E}(X^2) - \Bbb{E}((\Bbb{E}(X \mid Y))^2).
\end{align*}
The remaining is now straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I got to

$Var(\Bbb{E}(X|Y))+\Bbb{E}(Var(X|Y))=Var(X) + 2(\Bbb{E}(\Bbb{E}(X|Y)^2)-\Bbb{E}(X\Bbb{E}(X|Y)))$

So a possibility is to show

$\Bbb{E}(\Bbb{E}(X|Y)^2)-\Bbb{E}(X\Bbb{E}(X|Y))=0$

So I can proceed in the following way:

$\Bbb{E}(X\Bbb{E}(X|Y))=\Bbb{E}(\Bbb{E}(X\Bbb{E}(X|Y))|Y)$ Since $\Bbb{E}(X|Y)=g(Y)$ for some $g$, we have that $\Bbb{E}(\Bbb{E}(X\Bbb{E}(X|Y))|Y)=\Bbb{E}(\Bbb{E}(Xg(Y))|Y)=\Bbb{E}(g(Y)\Bbb{E}(X|Y))=\Bbb{E}(\Bbb{E}(X|Y)^2)$

And therefore, $\Bbb{E}(\Bbb{E}(X|Y)^2)-\Bbb{E}(X\Bbb{E}(X|Y))=0$ concluding that:

$Var(\Bbb{E}(X|Y))+\Bbb{E}(Var(X|Y))=Var(X)$